# React native get flatlist get distanceFromEnd value

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

edited to make it clearer:
I am trying to get the scroll distance from the current scroll position to the end of a list.

I am trying to distanceFromEnd value in a flatlist.  I can get the scroll amount using onScroll however i cant get the amount the list can scroll.  I can user layout to get the size of the scroll list but that amount is larger then the distance from end because it includes the non-scroll part (the size of the component).  For now I am using onEndReached to get the distanceFromEnd but it would be much better if i could get the amount on component load.  Does anyone know how to solve this problem?  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to know when each item in your FlatList mounts, renders, etc, which should give you the user's position in your list. Not in a position to write sample code at the moment, but if you're having trouble let me know.

Comment: Sorry to be clear I am not looking for the components position in the list, but the amount of pixels from the end the current scroll is

Answer (score 0):

Okay I worked it out.  I can use 
onScroll gets current scroll position
onLayout gets size of container
onContentSizeChange gets size of content

So distanceFromEnd = contentSize - contentContainer - scrollPosition